# Splitting ndarray features

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, multidimensional-array

Currently, I am working with the Hog and I want to take the certain array data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage import data, exposure

image = data.astronaut()
fd = hog(image,orientations=9,pixels_per_cell=(4,4),cells_per_block=(2,2),feature_vector=False)
fd.shape
```

The shape would be (127, 127, 2, 2, 9) 
How can I take the first, second and last value from this nested list
I want to take a array which has shape (127,127,9)

Thank you.

Comment: I actually have no idea how the array could be nested like that, i could not imagine :(( how it is arranged.

Answer (score 1):

You could just slice the given array like the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((127, 127, 2, 2, 9))
print(a.shape)
# (127, 127, 2, 2, 9)
b = a[:,:,0,0,:]
print(b.shape)
# (127, 127, 9)
```

But it depend on what exactly do you wish to slice from the HoG features